# How can I unblock resources in my robots.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

According to Google Webmasters tools, I have 145 blocked resources.

This is my `robots.txt`.

Is this the right  way to allow something in `robots.txt`? How can I unblock it?

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /nogooglebot/


 User-agent: *
 Allow: /



User-agent: Googlebot-news
 Allow: /


 User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
 Allow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow:/login
Allow:/router.infolinks.com/dyn/
Allow:/router.infolinks.com/dyn/zmn/
Allow:/ads.pubmatic.com/AdServer/js/
Sitemap:http://svidzdownloader.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Are your blocked resources in the /nogooglebot/ or /login/ directory?

Comment: noo google blocked my urls in google webmaster in the section of google index blocked resources

Comment: which urls did google block? give us an example of what Google tells you . E.g. resource/URL and Robots.txt. Does the page specifically say that it is robots.txt that's causing the problem?

Comment: i have 145 blocked resources in Google webmaster i want to know how to unblock the resources

Comment: It depends on why google blocked them, please give us an example of one and we might be able to help identify whether or not this is a programming problem that we can help with.

Comment: when i open y blocked url its showing me robor.txt file in there there was disAllow

Comment: We cant' tell you why google blocked a specific URL unless you give us the specific URL.

Comment: http://svidzdownloader.com/watch/top-10-new-april-games-of-2018/8FtfbByw5YY this is the url why google blocked this url a

Comment: and tell me how to allow link using robot.txt

Comment: Nothing wrong with the file with respect to that URL. Must be a problem with google.. Maybe just wait if you change the site recently as google take a while to update.